# Explicit forms for the roots of Eulerian polynomials

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, polynomials

Let $E_n(z)$ be the Eulerian polynomial
$$E_n(z) = \sum_{\tau \in \mathfrak{S}_n} z^{\operatorname{des}(\tau)}$$
where $\mathfrak{S}_n$ denotes the set of all permutations of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $\operatorname{des}(\tau)$ is the number of descents $\tau(i) > \tau(i+1)$ in the permutation $\tau$.
These are studied in great detail, see its [OEIS wiki page](http://oeis.org/wiki/Eulerian_polynomials) for other definitions and several properties.
In particular, it is known the Eulerian polynomial has only negative and simple roots,
$$E_n(z) = \prod_{i=1}^n (z+q^{(n)}_i)$$
for different positive numbers $q^{(n)}_i$.

My question now is

> What is known about the $q^{(n)}_i$'s? Do they have an explicit description?

(It is known that the roots of $E_n$ separate the roots of $E_{n+1}$.
This is,
$$q_1^{(n+1)} < q_1^{(n)} < \cdots < q_{n}^{(n+1)}< q_n^{(n)} < q_{n+1}^{(n+1)}$$
when they come in sorted order. That's *not* the type of property I am looking for, but only properties towards their explicit values.)

Here are the first two examples and the type of property I would like to have answered from a description I search for:

$$
\begin{align*}
E_2(z) &= z^2 + 4z + 1
        = (z+2-\sqrt{3})(z+2+\sqrt{3}) \\
E_3(z) &= z^3 + 11z^2 + 11z + 1
        = (z+5+2\sqrt{6})(z+5-2\sqrt{6})(z+1)
\end{align*}
$$

(The roots become more complicated than $a\pm b\sqrt{c}$ for bigger $n$'s.)

It is known that the mean value of the discrete distribution given by $E_n$ is $n/2$ and the variance is $(n+2)/12$.
This can be used to show that
$$
\begin{align*}
  \sum_i \frac{1}{1+q^{(n)}_i}                     &= \frac{n}{2} \\
  \sum_i \frac{q^{(n)}_i}{\big(1+q^{(n)}_i\big)^2} &= \frac{n+2}{12}
\end{align*}
$$

Doing this computation in the first example yields
$$
  \frac{1}{1+2+\sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{1+2-\sqrt{3}} = 1
$$
and
$$
  \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{(1+2+\sqrt{3})^2} + \frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{(1+2-\sqrt{3})^2} = \frac{1}{3}
$$

> Is there any known immediate property of the roots that can be used to get these identities?

Comment: As for the roots having an explicit description, if the Galois group of $E_n(z)$ were abelian then there would be a trigonometric formula for the roots. However, this is not the case. It is known that $E_n(z)$ is irreducible. By the symmetry of the coefficients, the largest possible Galois group has order $2^m m!$, where $m=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ (and is the hyperoctahedral group $B_m$) . It has been checked for $n\leq 9$ that $B_m$ is indeed the Galois group of $E_n(z)$, so one could conjecture that this is the case for all $n$.

Comment: I was mistaken when I said that it is known that $E_n(z)$ is irreducible. First, $E_{2m}(z)$ is divisible by $1+z$. It is only conjectured that $E_{2m+1}(z)$ and $E_{2m}(z)/(1+z)$ are irreducible. For some instances of irreducibility see https://ac.els-cdn.com/0022314X84900507/1-s2.0-0022314X84900507-main.pdf?_tid=b7851008-da37-11e7-b53d-00000aacb35f&acdnat=1512532029_b3fb036a2c51f85ecd4b170784622aa8.

Answer (score 7):

Here is some partial information.  If $E_n(z)=\sum A_n(i)x^i$, then
$A_n(i)$ grows roughly like $(i+1)^n$ for fixed $i$. Now $A_n(i)$ is
(up to sign) the $i$th elementary symmetric function of the
roots. Hence $|q_1^{(n)}|$ is about $2^n$. Then $|q_2^{(n)}|$ is about
$(3/2)^n$, $|q_3^{(n)}|$ is about $(4/3)^n$, etc. It is not hard to
show in fact that for fixed $i$,
     $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} |q_i^{(n)}|^{1/n} =
   \frac{i+1}{i}. $$
Note also that there is an explicit formula for $A_n(i)$ as a sum with
$i+2$ terms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number). Thus any
rational symmetric function of the roots can be written in terms of
these sums.

Comment: Isn't here the order of the $q_{i}^{(n)}$ reversed with respect to the question?